# How to check for root user in Makefile.am

Tags: makefile

I want to run a check like

```
if user is root then
  directorypath = /set/path/to/this/dir
else
  directorypath = /set/path/to/that/dir/instead
```

In my `Makefile.am` but I am unsure on what syntax to use to achieve this and whether or not I need to do something in `configure.ac` to make the conditional work. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Why do you feel it would be useful to know that?

Comment: Because this sounds very much like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). That is you've already made some incorrect or sub-optimal decisions that lead you to asking this question instead of the (better to ask) original question. (Additionally this sounds like you want to control installation paths and you shouldn't generally do that as-such that's what the prefix/DESTDIR stuff is for.)

Comment: @EtanReisner that's pseudocode. I am quite sure on what I want to do and that this needs to be done in my Makefile.am. If you can't cope with that, then I guess you're not the right person to help find the answer to this question.

Comment: Doing the root user check when processing the `Makefile.am` file is not possibly the right thing. Doing that at `make` execution time has at least a chance of being something you might (think) you want to do but is unlikely to actually be what you want to do (in all but very specialized situations). And even in those situations it remains unlikely to be the correct mechanism for this determination but <shrug>. I certainly don't need to try to help you.

Comment: @EtanReisner I think you need to learn the definition of help and then go seek it. Preferably somewhere else. :-)

Comment: @EtanReisner one last thing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxPb9GRP73o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

In `configure.ac`:

```
 AM_CONDITIONAL(USER, test `whoami` = "root")
```

In `Makefile.am`:

```
if USER
directorypath = /set/path/to/this/dir
else
directorypath = /set/path/to/that/dir/instead
endif
```

Simples.

Comment: This is a configure time test I believe and will not change things at `make` time.

Comment: Working at configure time? Sure. It will absolutely work. But go try running make as root (when configure was run as non-root) or vice versa and see which path you get.

Comment: @EtanReisner this is one of those "specialised situations" you unjustifiably inferred that I would not be able to fathom. This is a subdirectory Makefile.am and these specific directories I am setting are at make install. However, nobody needed to know that to be able to answer this very straightforward question. That notwithstanding, even if I had not known what I was doing at all, I do not think it excuses your XY remarks: As well as being presumptuous, rude and arrogant, it was an incredibly aggressive way to introduce yourself to anyone who is seeking help.

Comment: I didn't say anything about *your* ability to fathom anything and I didn't introduce myself that way. You did. I asked a question about your ultimate goal to which your response was not to answer my question but to question the need for the additional information I was requesting. And I still maintain that determining (at configure time) which installation paths to use (which will be used at `make` time) is both incorrect and very much the wrong way to handle this sort of situation. This sort of thing is *exactly* why the `--prefix` argument to configure and the `DESTDIR` make variable exist.

Comment: @EtanReisner you have no idea what my ultimate goal or what the situation is and yet you continue to assert that you do and also presume that my method is wrong. I doubt you would have answered this question even if you had known the answer (which I also doubt). From the offset you have been presumptuous, arrogant, rude, aggressive and now you seem to also be unable to accept the idea that you might have been wrong on any of those (many) levels. I guess we will have to agree to disagree.

Comment: You are right I **don't** know what your ultimate goal was **because you wouldn't tell me**. That was the **first** question I asked. I didn't know the answer to the autotool question. I could have found it with some looking I'm sure but I didn't, and still don't since you won't explain, think that it is the correct answer to the underlying question. But you are free, obviously, to solve this however you want.